# How to detect if app request resources

Tags: android, permissions, media

I'm searching for a way to detect when other apps are accessing media or sensors (e.g. microphone).

I want to implement a service that inform the user, once any app is accessing the microphone or camera.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks for help!